# How is the seaborn heatmap correlation calculated mathematically. And does it provide accuracy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, seaborn, heatmap

The heatmap provides measured correlation in resulting visuals, how is it exactly calculated? And is it accurate with relation?

Comment: "The heatmap provides numerically measured correlation" - does it? I think it simply "plots rectangular data as a color-encoded matrix": https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html.

Comment: Seaborn's heatmap doesn't calculate correlation. You need to calculate the correlation before, e.g. with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) or [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html). See their docs for more information.

Comment: When we use Heatmap we can see that somehow the correlation between the columns is calculated and presented in visuals (The resulted map ). I am not sure how the correlation is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's Heatmap uses correlation matrix as an argument to plot the heatmap.

A correlation matrix is simply a table which displays the correlation. The measure is best used in variables that demonstrate a linear relationship between each other.

The correlation matrix for a DataFrame can be calculated using:

```
df.corr()
```

Follow this [docs1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html#pandas-dataframe-corr) for information on the corr() function.

Also, follow [docs2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-seaborn-correlation-heatmap-in-python/) to know how correlation matrix is used inside heatmap.